# mysql query 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm messing around with a mysql query over 3 tables and and I just can't get it work.

The situation: I have 3 tables.

[image]

Now I try to make a mysql query based on an inputfield, where I put in a "oxid" from the table "oxarticles" and the result should be, that I get all the articles from the category where the article/oxid is which I put in the inputfield.

Example: I put "oxid" 2 in a inputfield and press submit and the result should looks like this:

```
Lenkrad
Reifen
Sitz
```

I tried a lot but never come close to. I made a day before another query that show me all the categories based on a article but I cant modified that and used it for my actual problem.

I hope you  can help me :)

Thats what I get so far, but I think this is not even close cause I get a white page.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT oxtitle FROM oxarticles a
INNER JOIN oxobject2category b ON a.oxid = b.oxobjectid
WHERE b.oxcatnid IN (SELECT oxcatnid FROM oxobject2category WHERE oxobjectid = 2)")

or die(mysql_error());  ;
```

Comment: please post relevant sql query to your question

Comment: I have nothing useable yet cause all my trys ended with a white page. You mean that I should post my try-query for this, right?

Comment: we want to see what you did, and how you did it.  Then we can give answers, point you in the right direction etc.  That way we can correct your thought process.  Teaching a man to fish is far better then giving him one. ;)

Comment: Are your `oxid`s really `#.#` ?

Comment: yes this is how it is in the mysql table

Comment: Your query seems correct. Are you sure the rest of the PHP code does not have a problem?

Answer (score -2):

Now i got it:

The follow querys work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT oxtitle FROM oxarticles a
INNER JOIN oxobject2category b ON a.oxid = b.oxobjectid
WHERE b.oxcatind IN (SELECT oxcatind FROM oxobject2category WHERE oxobjectid = 2
```

and this one also:

```
select distinct
  a.oxtitle
from
  oxarticles a,
  oxobject2category oc
where
  a.oxid = oc.oxobjectid and
  oxcatind in (select oxcatind from oxobject2category where oxobjectid=2
```

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: It's highly unlikely that a syntactically correct query (as in your question) does NOT work while syntactically invalid ones (like these ones where both have missing parenthesis) do work.

Comment: Yes, it was bad mistake in my syntax code after the query and thats why it doesnt work. So my try from the first post was correct. No comment...